# Maximize Optimization using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to solve this linear programming function with the restraints shown below, the answer for `x1` and `x2` should be `2` and `6` respectively, and the value of the objective function should be equal to `36`. The code that I wrote gives me as answers `4` and `3`. What may I be doing wrong? Function to maximize `z=3*x1 + 5*x2`. Restraints are `x1 <= 4`;`2*x2 <=12`; `3*x1 + 2*x2 <= 18`;  `x1>=0`;`x2>=0`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def objective(x, sign=1.0):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    return sign*((3*x1) + (5*x2))
def constraint1(x, sign=1.0):
    return sign*(3*x[0] +2*x[1]- 18.0)
x0=[0,0]

b1 = (0,4)
b2 = (0,12)
bnds= (b1,b2)
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}

cons = [con1]
sol = minimize (objective,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)

print(sol)
```

Comment: Thank you @Stelios ,I just made the changes based on your suggestions and get the answer. I got -35.99, I guess the negative sign is because the algorithm give the answer based on a minimize  asumption instead of maximize.

Answer (score 16):

Your code has the following issues:

- The way you are passing your `objective` to `minimize` results in a *minimization* rather than a *maximization* of the objective. If you want to *maximize*   `objective` with `minimize` you should set the `sign` parameter to `-1`. See the maximization example in scipy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize).
- `minimize` assumes that the value returned by a constraint function is *greater* than zero. Therefore, the way you have written your constraint implies that `3*x1 + 2*x2 - 18.0 >=0`, whereas the actual constraint employs `<=`.
- The upper bound in `b2` does not correspond to the bound implied by the constraint `2*x2 <= 12`.

Comment: Couldnt get the sign parameter to work. the sign the parameter is not in the link of documentation you posted either.

Comment: @user1559897 Apparently, the documentation has been updated and the "sign" approach has been dropped, which I think it is appropriate as it is mostly confusing than providing any convenience. Just provide the sign "manually" as part of the objective function output

Comment: Can you give an example for that?

Comment: @shredding maximization of a function `f` is equivalent to minimization of `-f`

Answer (score 5):

If anyone wants the working code, below it is. I have also added with cvx. The solution is x: array([2., 6.])

```
def objective(x, sign=-1.0):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    return sign*(3*x1 + 5*x2)

def constraint1(x):
    return 18.0 - 3*x[0] -2*x[1]

x0 = [0,0]

b1 = (0,4)
b2 = (0,6)
bnds= (b1,b2)
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
cons = [con1]
sol = minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)

print(sol)
```

### CVXPY

```
 # Create two scalar optimization variables (CVXPY Variable)
 x1 = cp.Variable()
 x2 = cp.Variable()
 # Create two constraints (Python list)
 constraints = [3*x1 + 2*x2 <= 18, x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, x1 <=4, x2 <= 6]
 # Form objective
 obj = cp.Maximize(3*x1 + 5*x2)
 # Form and solve problem
 prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
 prob.solve() # Returns the optimal value.
 print("status:", prob.status)
 print("optimal value", np.round(prob.value, 5))
 print("optimal var", np.round(x1.value, 5), np.round(x2.value, 5))
```