# Non-linear optimizations in python?

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

What is the best way to solve a constrained non linear optimization problem in python?

Type of problem is highly non-convex:

Maximize

```
A*log(1+x1)*y1 + B*log(1+x2)*y2 + C*log(1+x3)*y3
```

subjected to

```
x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3*y3 <= K;
l1 <= x1*y1 <= u1;
l2 <= x2*y2 <= u2;
l3 <= x3*y3 <= u3;
where xi's & yi's are variables and A,B,C,K,li's & ui's are constants
```

Any recommendations for the solver or the API's I should explore

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, checkout [Scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint.html#scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint)

The NonlinearConstraint functionality was basically designed for things like this.
Just change your lambda function to include the relevant constraint

Also worth checking out these other answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43704112/3456886
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43162017/3456886