# scipy.optimize.minimize to find intersection of curves

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

to find intersection between 2 polynomials I tried to minimize *sum of least-squares* like in [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72154674/15893581) - first plotted correct solution, then printed result of minimization.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)    # ???????? [0,1]

def polyD(x):
    return  1.115355004199118 - 1.597163991790283* x**1 + 0.6539311181514963* x**2
def polyS(x):
    return -0.03070291735792586 + 0.1601011622660309* x**1 + 0.8530319920733438* x**2

root= 0.61      # x - suppose found somewhere earlier...
y_root= polyD(root) # y
print(root, y_root) # x=0.61 y=0.38441273827121725

plt.plot(root, y_root, 'yo',   x, polyD(x), 'r-', x, polyS(x), 'b-', ms=20, )
plt.show()

####################

from scipy.optimize import minimize

x0=  0
res= minimize(lambda t: sum((polyD(x) - polyS(x))**2), x0)

print(res)
print(res.fun)  # 36.59096676853359 ????????????
```

I can assume a little difference due to the algorithm, but here I see the difference of 10^2 order.

What is my mistake?? How can I correct it? If I should define some constraints to x=[0,1]? or how to get correct result about the intersection_point?

P.S. or, perhaps, it will be easier to solve with derivatives (minimizing to find extremum)? EDIT: partial_derivatives of constrained function(s) (Jacobian matrix) can be used to speed-up the code execution - [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/optimize.html#defining-bounds-constraints)

Comment: Your lambda function specifies parameter `t`, but you are using `x` (which happens to be a vector you also defined earlier, which is why you had to make a `sum` here as well.

Comment: And the issue you link the user is artificially limited to using `minimize`. You can of course use `fsolve` if you want.

Comment: GREAT! thanks a lot for your fresh_view to the code! I corrected...  it works: *plt.plot(res.x, polyD(res.x), 'yo',   x, polyD(x), 'r-', x, polyS(x), 'b-', ms=20, )*

Comment: yes, it also works with *fsolve*: `solution_x = opt.fsolve(f, x0=[1], full_output=True)` when `f= lambda x: sum((polyD(x) - polyS(x))**2)`

Comment: ... or *fsolve* without lambda, just with func defined as `def f(x) : d = polyD(x).sum(); s = polyS(x).sum();  res= [d- s]; return res`... *sum()* is important anyway

Comment: "optimize.least_squares does the calculation of the chi-squared internally, while  using scipy.optimize.minimize  you have to calculate the chi-squared manually inside the function you want to minimize" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49211783/15893581)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `minimize` and don't use `fsolve`; use `Polynomial` and its built-in `.roots`:

```
poly_d = Polynomial((1.115355004199118, -1.597163991790283, 0.6539311181514963))
poly_s = Polynomial((-0.03070291735792586, 0.1601011622660309, 0.8530319920733438))

for x in (poly_d - poly_s).roots():
    print(f'd({x:.2f}) = {poly_d(x):.2f}')
    print(f's({x:.2f}) = {poly_s(x):.2f}')
```

```
d(-9.44) = 74.41
s(-9.44) = 74.41
d(0.61) = 0.38
s(0.61) = 0.38
```

Or since this is only order 2, you may also solve it analytically.

```py
c, b, a = poly_d - poly_s
u = 0.5/a
d = np.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)
x0 = u*(d - b)
x1 = u*(-d - b)
```

Comment: I did,`roots = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots(np.polynomial.polynomial.polysub(poly_coeffS, poly_coeffD)); x_int = roots[(roots >= x.min()) & (roots <= x.max())]; y_int = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x_int, poly_coeffD)` - But, as stated in the topic's title, wanted to solve my misunderstanding of optimization from scipy. I used *np.polinomial* just to fit random initial data, therefore polynomials were used in optimization problem, but equations assumed to be any in reality

Comment: OK, but if you want practice on `minimize`, use it when it's the right tool for the job. Here, it's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` & `scipy.optimize.root_scalar()` also suit for such data... though Numpy is faster (as it is written in C), but SciPy "contains more fully-featured versions of the linear algebra modules, as well as many other numerical algorithms" - it is just the question of preference... fsolve function returns the roots of a non linear equation defined by f(x)=0... I didn't care about this - just wanted to solve/minimize any **Convex Problem**

Comment: still am not sure how to find global minimum wihout [looping](https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/BlackBoxOptimization.html) all roots...

Comment: What does that even mean? There's more than one global minimum. This is not a job for an opaque minimizer. Minimizers generally aren't designed to do this, and only seek out one minimum.

Comment: well, concerning my last confusion, really there's [Numerical Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620541/finding-extremum-values-in-a-given-function-using-hessian-matrix?rq=1): if the problem is [Convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1527388/1121385), than local minimum (with Grad>0 curving-up & Hessian flat[=0] at stationary point) is [global](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2193848/1121385) minimum - .. and [check](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402105/1121385) unbounded condition... and [solution with no calculus at all](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4341324/1121385)

Comment: @ Reinderien: "more than one global minimum" [not local !] exists only in periodic functions, as I thought... – but really still in the other case - [e.g.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/864689/1121385) link already attached

Comment: really, there are different functions in [SciPy.Optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/optimize.html) (icl. Global min finding, or [to find max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43704112/15893581) - multiply to -1, [e.g.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximize-optimization-using-scipy/)

Comment: found methods for [global](https://machinelearningmastery.com/function-optimization-with-scipy/) optimization - they are stochastic ones

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because of this line:

```py
lambda t: sum((polyD(x) - polyS(x))**2)
```

Notice anything wrong? You used `x` instead of `t`. Swap those `x`s for `t`s and you get your desired results.

Alternatively, you could use `scipy.optimize.root`. Below I show both methods, though I only apply bounds to the `minimize` method.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, root


def polyD(x):
    return 1.115355004199118 - 1.597163991790283*x**1 + 0.6539311181514963*x**2


def polyS(x):
    return -0.03070291735792586 + 0.1601011622660309*x**1 + 0.8530319920733438*x**2


def f(x):
    return polyD(x) - polyS(x)


def g(x):
    return np.sum(f(x)**2)


x0 = 0
min_res = minimize(g, x0, bounds=[(0, 1)])
root_res = root(f, x0)

print(min_res)
print(root_res)
```

Output:

```py
  message: CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL
  success: True
   status: 0
      fun: 7.999974469252813e-13
        x: [ 6.100e-01]
      nit: 5
      jac: [-3.538e-06]
     nfev: 12
     njev: 6
 hess_inv: <1x1 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>

 message: The solution converged.
 success: True
  status: 1
     fun: [ 6.772e-15]
       x: [ 6.100e-01]
    nfev: 7
    fjac: [[-1.000e+00]]
       r: [ 2.000e+00]
     qtf: [ 6.131e-09]
```

Comment: already was SOLVED in comments to starting message - thanks to Mikael Öhman

Answer (score 0):

another solution, probably: to use difference of functions as `eq` constraint:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)

def fd(x):
    return  1.115355004199118 - 1.597163991790283* x**1 + 0.6539311181514963* x**2
def fs(x):
    return -0.03070291735792586 + 0.1601011622660309* x**1 + 0.8530319920733438* x**2

plt.plot(  x, fs(x), 'r-', x, fd(x), 'b-')
plt.show()

######################

cons = ( { 'type' : 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: fs(x)-fd(x)} )

res = minimize(fs, [0., ],   constraints= cons,  tol=1.4e-100)
if res.success== True: print(res.x , ' ~ ', fd(res.x), '\n')
else: res.message

plt.plot(res.x, fd(res.x), 'yo', x, fd(x), 'r-', x, fs(x), 'b-', ms=20, )
plt.show()
```

really, code_design can vary, giving needed result, I suppose.

As I understand: we can use constraints for ys & bounds for xs. (?)